# LDA visualization [ import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors' ]

Tags: python, gensim, lda, pyldavis

i got a error message while visualizing LDA model

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(ldamodel,corpus, dictionary)
vis
```

and it gives me error message
" import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'"

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: No still not yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error. The older version of `import_optional_dependency()`  doesn't have the argument 'error'.

Check your pandas version :

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```

If your version is less than 1.3, install the updated version :

```
!pip install pandas==1.3.1
```

or

```
!pip install pandas --upgrade
```

That worked for me.